# Web Config Rewrite/redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I am working on an existing project that I did not create.

In the web.config file, there are a number of redirects, setup in the following way:

```
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
          <add key="/findyourlocalbranch/" value="/find-your-local-branch/" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
```

It seems to me that a rewrite rule is being used to do these redirects, but as I said, I did not write this and am not in a position to change this. I am not sure if this is right or wrong.

My problem is that I need to implement the following redirect:

```
<add key="/need-a-loan/.htm" value="/need-a-loan/" />
```

but this brings the whole site down - I suspect due to a syntax error in this line.

I suspect the error is the '.' after the '/'

My question is, what can I do about it - there is nothing on the internet that I can find about this.

Basically, I want to redirect this one, specific URL to the given URL???

Comment: What do you have in the `<rewrite><rules>` section ? I'm not sure what that map is for

Comment: Also, are you just trying to rediect `/need-a-loan/_(anything)_.htm` to `/need-a-loan/` ?

Comment: @NikolaiDante there are rewrite rules iin the web config, but this needs to be a specific redirect only for this URL and nothing else. There are other sub pages from this URL

Comment: A map doesn't mean much without a rule that has something like `<add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />`. Or `RuleName:` if "Redirects" isn't the real one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say whats going on with the map, as without the corresponding rule I'm blind.

But, this rewrite rule will redirect from `/need-a-loan/.htm` to `/need-a-loan/`.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Need-A-Loan" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="need-a-loan/.htm" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="need-a-loan/"  redirectType="Permanent"  />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Note: doesn't use the map, so you'd remove that entry.

That will give you a 301. If you want a different type, you can adjust the `rediectType`. E.g. `Temporary` will give you a 307.